# Is there an easy way to provide a link to an online event after user has registered?

Tags: civievent, urls

To start, I am looking for a purely civicrm solution.

I simply want to include a link to the webinar, livestream, etc. When the user registers, in their confirmation email, a link to the online location of the event will be included in the body of the email, and hopefully in eventics.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a custom field to the event, with that link as the value, and then reference that field in the receipt templates, eg using Fuzion Token extension (though not sure it is offered)

Comment: How is the link to the online location of the event stored in Civi?  Is it a custom field?  Or something else?

Comment: Currently, it is stored in the "street address" field, and we have "show location?" unchecked. We can store in a custom field if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM uses the "system workflow templates" "Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (off-line)" and Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)" for its automated event emails.

You would need to edit those to include general information you would like to display for each event. This can be a bit tricky as all kind of process logic is crammed in the template but it should be doable. Be aware that you can use api calls to pull certain parameters in order to use within the template.

Additionally, in every event configuration screen (tab online registration) there should be a little text box that allows you to add some event specific text to the email.

If for some reasons that does not work for you, you may want to get in contcact with us as we are currently developing a coherent "event email extension" that allows users to easily set up event mails with certain trigger rules and provide many additional features. We are still looking for funding to complete the extension and it's documentation.

Comment: The issue is that the confirmation text box is plain text, if it was wysiwyg, it would be a non issue.

Comment: If you put in in a custom field as suggested by pete, you could use a call like this to pull the data into the template: {crmAPI var='xyz' entity='Event' action='getvalue' sequential=0 return="custom_123" id=$event.whatever}. You could the use {$xyz} in the template to render the field's content.